# Blender output files IGS or STEP?

Tags: file-format

Is there any update to the IGS or STEP files format questions?

IF you NEED to go to CNC for molds, etc., is/are there any good converters to get the stl (Blender) file to igs or step?

TY

markg

Comment: Not really sure,but as far as I know IGS files are NURBS or ACIS Solid modeling CAD file formats, they can't really hold mesh based data that Blender primarily produces, but I may be wrong.